# Is there a closed form solution to the following system of SDEs?

Tags: bond, sde, vasicek, continuous-time

Suppose we have the system
\begin{align}
dr_t=\alpha_r(x_t-r_t)dt+\sigma_rdW_t^r\\
dx_t=\alpha_x(\bar{x}-x_t)dt+\sigma_xdW_t^x\\
\end{align}

As this system is affine, I believe there should be an easy way to derive the closed-form solutions? Or at least numerically using ODEs. I know there are closed-form solutions for the two-factor Vasicek model. However, I am new to continuous time processes and still learning, and this setting does not exactly conform to the two-factor Vasicek system (note for instance no instantaneous correlation). Suppose, you wish to find the price of a bond, with the instantaneous short-term rate $r_t$, is their an exponential affine solution for such system? E.g. in the form of

\begin{equation}
P(0,T)=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[e^{-\int_0^Tr_sds}\right]=e^{a_t+b_tr}
\end{equation}
Assuming that $P(T,T)=1$ and both the system and expectation are under the risk neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$.

Following, @kurtG. 's comment, and having looked at his response at the other post, how would that exactly look like in matrix form? You'd have:
\begin{equation}
d
\begin{pmatrix}
r_t\\
x_t
\end{pmatrix}=
\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
\alpha_x\bar{x}
\end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_r & -\alpha_r\\
0 & \alpha_x
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
r_t\\
x_t
\end{pmatrix}
\right)
dt
+
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_r &0\\
0&\sigma_x
\end{pmatrix}
d
\begin{pmatrix}
W_t^r\\
W_t^x
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

In that representation, wouldn't you have identification issue when calibrating?

Comment: There is. You can write this in vector/matrix form and follow [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4435304/integration-of-matrix-form-of-vasicek-variance-python-matlab/4435766#4435766).

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for your input. I have edited the question to reflect your comment. Wouldn't you have identification issue in such setting? Or have I completely misunderstood?

Comment: This looks correct.

Comment: @KurtG. But then in this case the matrices, say $K$, as per the link you shared with me,  do not commute and the last line cannot be simplified for the covariance matrix

Comment: Could be. However, you asked only for a solution to the SDE system, not for a covariance matrix.